# FacebookSDK mismatch

Tags: android

I want to do Login with facebook.But when I am going to Create a new Android Project with Facebook Login I got the error of the Jar mismatch.

when I create new android application that time there is no any errors, but when add the FacebookSDK to the newly create project. that time it gives 
Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies  |   Unknown Android Dependency Problem

I tried everything to change the java compiler level but not getting.

I tried project properties > Java compiler > In this level I do all changes of the java versions, but not success.

any help please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its mean there is multiple jar file(with same name) in you Project and Library Project. just Delete that jar file form Project.(not from Library Project)

or rename your one of jar file.(i ll sagest you delete jar file instead of rename)

Comment: It still marks me an error I deleted the file
android-support-v4.jar
I realized that there are two files with the same name of the project folder and the other in facebooksdk.
There is another way?

Comment: just add android-support-v4.jar file in FB SDK. in your Project you have to add FB SDK(add as library).

Comment: I did as you said and I still have an error
What should I do? : ((

Comment: [2013-04-30 14:27:51 - FacebookApp] Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies  All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.